# Chrome overflow:auto issue after ajax operation

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, scroll

As part of a page I am filling a div

```
{width:496px; height:640px; overflow-x: hidden ; overflow-y:auto; }
```

with ajax calls:

```
function ajaxcall(program, param) {
$("#ajaxloader").html("<IMG src='ajax-loader.gif'>");
$("#content").hide(); $("#ajaxloader").show();
$.ajax(
    {
    url: program,
    type:"POST",
    data: { "param":param },
    success: function(back)
        {
        $("#ajaxloader").hide();
        $("#content").html(back);
        $("#content").fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
}
```

Depending on the mouse position, Chrome fills in the ajax content partly or completely outside of visible content div area. Safari, Firefox all work fine, chrome doesn't.
My research was unsuccesful so far. Trying a complete overflow:auto didnt work. Anyone a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set, overflow-y: hidden and overflow-y: auto back again. I hope it will helps. (I hate browsers differences)

Comment: Thx, androbin, but negative. Same behaviour.